# Call to collect() doesn't return after called on rdd produced by combineByKey function

Tags: java, apache-spark

Disclaimer : I am new to Spark

I have an rdd which looks like :

`[(T,[Tina, Thomas]), (T,[Tolis]), (C,[Cory, Christine]), (J,[Joseph, Jimmy, James, Jackeline, Juan]), (J,[Jimbo, Jina])]`

and i call combineByKey and get as a result a JavaPairRDD< Character, Integer >

This call seems to work correct (the control flow passes from this point and in the debugger foo seems to have some kind of value)

```
JavaPairRDD<Character, Integer> foo = rdd.combineByKey(createAcc, addAndCount, combine);
System.out.println(foo.collect());
```

My problem is that the program doesn't return after call to foo.collect();
Do you have any ideas ? I tried to debug with the eclipse debugger but i had no chance at all

I am using Spark version 2.0.0 and Java 8

EDIT : the code for the functions called by combineByKey is the following (it is obviously a dummy code cause i am new to spark , my goal with the call to 
combineByKey is to find the total length of the lists of strings beloning to each Key) :

```
            Function<Iterable<String>, Integer> createAcc =

            new Function<Iterable<String>, Integer>() {

                    public Integer call(Iterable<String> x) {
                            int counter = 0;
                            Iterator<String> it = x.iterator();
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                    counter++;
                            }
                            return counter;
                    }
            };

            Function2<Integer, Iterable<String>, Integer> addAndCount =

            new Function2<Integer,Iterable<String>, Integer>() {

                    public Integer call(Integer acc , Iterable<String> x) {
                            int counter = 0;
                            Iterator<String> it = x.iterator();
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                    counter++;
                            }
                            return counter + acc;
                    }
            };

            Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer> combine =

            new Function2<Integer,Integer, Integer>() {

                    public Integer call(Integer x, Integer y) {
                            return x+y;
                    }
            };
```

UPDATE2 : the requested log is the following

`16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at Foo.java:265
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 9 (count at Foo.java:265) with 3 output partitions
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 20 (count at Foo.java:265)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 19, ShuffleMapStage 18)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 20 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at combineByKey at Foo.java:264), which has no missing parents
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_12 stored as values in memory (estimated size 6.7 KB, free 1946.0 MB)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_12_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.4 KB, free 1946.0 MB)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_12_piece0 in memory on xxx.xxx.xx.xx:55712 (size: 3.4 KB, free: 1946.1 MB)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 12 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 20 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at combineByKey at Foo.java:264)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 20.0 with 3 tasks
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 30, localhost, partition 0, ANY, 5288 bytes)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 30)
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 2 non-empty blocks out of 3 blocks
16/11/11 17:21:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms`

Comment: what is the size of the data? what is the result of "foo.count()"?

Comment: The size of the data is pretty small (the rdd i am using to expirement is the one posted in the question). Call to foo.count() doesn't seem to return either (i assume it is for the same reason).

Comment: The combineByKey transformation gets executed only when you call an action (count ou collect for example). The problem is probably in the combineByKey functions. Could you give more details ?

Comment: @Marie i updated the original post (you can see the code for the functions invoked by combineByKey)

Comment: Is there nothing in the log? It should point you to the right place. Mind that until you call an action (like collect) no calculations are triggered. combineByKey is a transformation. You can't say that it worked correct just because it passed to the new line. JavaPairRDD is not a "result", it's just a step that was defined in chain.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I posted the log above but due to the fact that i am new to spark i can't understand a lot ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple Java issue: your "while" loops never call it.next, and never end.

Change them to

```
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      it.next();
      counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Seems that I am the  biggest noob ever 